# Vim syntax enable/on

Tags: vim

There are two ways to make "syntax on" in Vim: `syntax enable` and `syntax on`. What preferred to put into `vimrc`? What the difference between them? I have read `:h :syn-qstart` and don't feel the difference.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-qstart : "*The `:syntax enable` command will keep your current color settings.  This allows using `:highlight` commands to set your preferred colors before or after using this command. **If you want Vim to overrule your settings with the defaults, use `:syntax on`***" (emphasize mine — *phd*)

Comment: I've  read this but don't fill what better. That's why I'm asking. Any offers?

Comment: Neither one. You choose not what is "better" but what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is more or less given at `:h syntax_cmd`. Basically, what Vim does is

```
let g:syntax_cmd = enable ? "enable" : "on"
source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim
unlet g:syntax_cmd
```

So the difference (if any) is how runtime files (actually, `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syncolor.vim` which gets sourced through `synload.vim` which, in turn, is sourced through `syntax.vim`) treat the value of `syntax_cmd` variable.

"Enabled"-version uses `:hi def` to set the colors for standard syntax groups, while "on"-version just `:hi`. But you need to do something rather tricky to encounter any difference.

```
$ vim -u NONE
:colo blue
:scr 1
:unlet g:colors_name
:syn enable
: "text is colored with "blue" colorscheme
:syn on
: "background is still "blue" but many colors now come from "default"
```

So usually `syntax enable` is slightly preferred, but you may just ignore this. At least, I'm not able to imagine a truly realistic situation where it matters.

Comment: I came for the tracing of which runtime scripts are actually loaded during `:syn on`. Thanks =)